# Why wont the animation rotates?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I was trying to use KivyMD to create an animation for a loading screen but the "Rotate" does not work properly. I followed a tutorial and tweaked it a bit so that it can be used with "ScreenManager" but only the rotating part is not working.

this is the python file

test.py

```
from platform import platform

from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp

Builder.load_file("test.kv")

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



class LoadingWindow(Screen):

    angle = 45

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoadingWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)



    def loading(self,  *kwargs):
        load = self.manager.get_screen("loadingwindow")
        anim = Animation(height=80, width=80, spacing=[10, 10], duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(height=60, width=60, spacing=[5, 5], duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(angle =  self.angle ,duration=0.5)
        print(self.angle)
        self.angle += 45
        anim.bind(on_complete=self.loading)
        anim.start(load.ids.loading)






class MyMainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"  # Choose a darker color palette, like "Gray"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "800"
        self.theme_cls.secondary_palette = "Grey"

        if platform == 'android' or platform == 'ios':
            Window.maximize()
        else:
            Window.size = (620, 1024)
        return WindowManager()


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

This is th kv file  that includes the ScreenManager

test.kv

```
<WindowManager>:
    LoadingWindow:


<LoadingWindow>
    name : "loadingwindow"
    MDGridLayout:
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle : root.angle
                origin: root.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color : 0,0,0,0
        MDGridLayout:
            id:loading
            angle : 0
            rows:2
            cols:2
            size_hint: None,None
            height:60
            width:60
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
            spacing:5
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color:rgba(242,80,34,255)
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color:rgba(242,80,34,255)
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color:rgba(242,80,34,255)
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color:rgba(242,80,34,255)
    MDRectangleFlatButton :
        id : load_button
        text : "Proceed"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.25}
        on_release :
            root.loading()
```

I was trying to use KivyMD to create an animation for a loading screen but the "Rotate" does not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding some `canvas` instructions to the `MDGridLayout` that you want to rotate. Here is a modified version of that `MDGridLayout`:

```
    MDGridLayout:
        id:loading
        angle : 0
        rows:2
        cols:2
        size_hint: None,None
        height:60
        width:60
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        spacing:5
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: self.angle
                axis: 0,0,1
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
```

Then the `loading()` method can be:

```
def loading(self,  *kwargs):
    loading_grid = self.ids.loading
    anim = Animation(height=80, width=80, spacing=[10, 10], duration=0.5)
    anim += Animation(height=60, width=60, spacing=[5, 5], duration=0.5)
    anim += Animation(angle=loading_grid.angle + 45, duration=0.5)
    anim.bind(on_complete=self.loading)
    anim.start(loading_grid)
```